# Dropdown onclick without js, php or target

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, menu, onclick

I want to make onclick dropdown menu without JavaScript, also PHP can't be used. I was using targets, but page jumps every time I click on it, because it is not on the top of page.
Is it possible to make dropdown menu without JS and PHP, but onclick?

Comment: What do you think `onclick` is supposed to be?  AFAIK, that's just a JavaScript event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are after is actually possible, though *I would not advise you to actually use this technique*. It is nothing less then a hack, semanticly very incorrect, and probably a nightmare for SEO.

This taken into account, I will explain the technique as a proof of concept:

First make sure you organise your **html** like this:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li> 
            <label for='item-1'>main item 1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="item-1"/>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">sub 1</a></li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Some smart use of the `:checked` selector and the sibling `+` selector now allows you to simulate a dropdown on click. The relevant **css** would look like this:

```
/* we hide the checkboxes, they are just there to store the 'state' in the background */
/* their state will be triggered by clicking the corresponding label */
nav input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}
/* we hide the sub menu's by default */
nav > ul > li > ul {
   display: none;   
}
/* we show the sub menu, if it follows a checked checkbox */
nav input[type="checkbox"]:checked + ul {
   display: block;   
}
```

For a working example, check the fiddle i set up: http://jsfiddle.net/Xj8Ce/

Answer (score 0):

If you want "onclick" event, you need JavaScript.
With hover you can try this: http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu

Hope it helps!